# How to Populate AutoCompleteTextView in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am Developing a small Dictionary App Using Sqlite Database Where There are Two Columns..Word and Word Definition.. Now how can I  populate AutoCompleteTextView So that When an user start to Type any Word for Searching I can Show him/her All the Words from word Column based On his/her first typed Letter?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post some code. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checkout the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), there's a good example on how to use AutoCompleteTextView there.

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.countries);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
             findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
    };
}
```

Using the above example you would just need to retrieve your words into the array and pass it to the adapter.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please don't forget to mark my answer as correct